# Creating a function in JS

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

I am curious to which is best pratice when creating a function in js

```
function x() {
    ...
}
```

OR

```
var x = function() {
    ...
}
```

Is there a difference or are they the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x(); // I work
function x() {
    ...
}
y(); // I fail
var y = function() {
    ...
}
```

The first is a function declaration. You can use functions before you've declared them.

The second is a assigning a function to a variable. This means you can assign to anything.

You can assing it to `foo[0]` or `foo.bar.baz` or `foo.get("baz")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first form because it gets defined before variables are defined.

So, you could invoke `x` in a later scope because the interpreter already defined that function even though it may be declared later on in your code.

This will be simpler with some code:

```
x(); //logs "hi"

//...
function x() { 
   console.log("hi"); 
}
```

vs

```
x(); //fails

var x = function() { 
   console.log("hi");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

They are not exactly the same thing, people have mentioned the forward-lookahead difference, here's a less known subtlety - the function name property:

```
function x(){}
x.name; // "x"

var x = function(){};
x.name; // ""
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you can pass functions as parameters and store them in arrays

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 0):

The first is a function *declaration*, the latter is a function *expression*. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) while I try to find a very in-depth article I once read on the differences and implications.

**Edit**: Ah, [here we go](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/). Grab a cup of tea and settle in for an in-depth discussion.